# How to give a meaningful hostname (XYZ.com), replacing "localhost:8080" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, localhost

I recently started working with Jenkins for CI/CD for ASP.net applications.
I have built a Jenkins server and created the required jobs with appropriate plugins.

My Jenkins is configured with localhost:8080 initially.
Later I was asked to give a meaningful host name (xyz.com), so that with in the organization all IT employees can access without logging in to the server to access Jenkins.

I have already tried to change the configurations under manage Jenkins -> Configure -> Jenkins Location (Jenkins URL), changed it to "localhost:80" and added "127.0.0.1 xyz.com" in the host file.

I have changed the port number in Jenkins.xml file even.
It didn't work for me because I had to browse "xyz.com:8080"

My final result should be "xyz.com" and should be accessible for the entire team.(I will take care of DNS).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart Jenkins after changing the port number in jenkins.xml?

Comment: Yes, I did restart Jenkins.

Comment: Is this on Windows? How are you starting Jenkins up?

Comment: Yes, it is on Windows, and I have stopped and started the service after the change, through command prompt.

Comment: Is it possible some other service (like IIS) is already bound to port 80 and preventing Jenkins from using it?

Comment: I see no service is running other than Jenkins on port 80.